# Simple Loop in python3 shell (version 3.81) SyntaxError

Tags: python-3.x

I can not understand why this is not working in a python3 shell:

```
>>> import random
>>> arr = [[]]
>>> for i in range(3):
...     a = random(sample(range(1,50),6)
...     arr[0].append(a)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    arr[0].append(a)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

But it works in a python file:

```
    1 import random
    2 
    3 arr = [[]]
    4 
    5 for i in range(14):
    6     a = random.sample(range(1, 50), 6)
    7     arr[0].append(a)
    8 print(arr)
```

Comment: `a = random(sample(range(1,50),6)` this line is not the same as the one in your python file

Answer (score 0):

```
#         v
a = random(sample(range(1,50),6)
a = random.sample(range(1,50),6)
#         ^
```

These lines are *not* the same, I've even put in the extra effort to show *how* they differ in case it's not immediately obvious :-)

The first one, with unbalanced parentheses, leads to an error showing up for the line following it, because it detects you haven't terminated the statement correctly.